# Cannot load modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server

Tags: windows, apache, svn

apache24のhttpd.confに以下を追記しました。

```
# subversion
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

すると、サービスが開始できません。
そして、このようなエラーがでます。

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 188 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: \x8ew\x92\xe8\x82\xb3\x82\xea\x82\xbd\x83\x82\x83W\x83\x85\x81[\x83\x8b\x82\xaa\x8c\xa9\x82\xc2\x82\xa9\x82\xe8\x82\xdc\x82\xb9\x82\xf1\x81
```

mod_dav_svn.soとmod_authz_svn.soが、SVN（tortoisesvn）に存在しなかったので、 https://github.com/nono303/win-svn/tree/master/vc15/x64 からファイルをダウンロードし、"C:\Apache24\modules"へ移動させました。

私はWindows 11のx64を使用しています。